# How do you change the drawable image on a button with text to reflect pressed state in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a Button with text and an image, where both the text and image change when the Button is in the pressed state.  All of the other questions about Buttons and images addressed changing the background in the pressed state, but none commented on changing the image drawable in the foreground.

Comment: Please edit this question to ask the question, and provide your own answer below. You will be able to accept your answer.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Appreciate your effort. But this is not the way it's done. *Why?* Since [so] is a Q&A site and not a forum, so you first need to ask a valid (go through the [help/on-topic] and [ask]) question. Then you can answer your own question by properly addressing the issue and the propose a solution (go through [answer]) or even multiple solutions in different answers. An answer to the question should not be part of the question, therefore please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks - apparently I have to wait 8 hours since this is my first question on stack overflow, but I will update my question and answer tomorrow!

Comment: Format of question/answer fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a state selector for both the text color of the button and the image used as the drawable.

Here's how you do it:

layout/my_layout.xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_action_delete"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/test_button_drawable"
    android:textColor="@color/link_text_red"
    android:text="Test Button"
    android:onClick="buttonDelete" />
```

drawable/test_button_drawable.xml:  (bottom_action_delete_image and bottom_action_delete_image_pressed are PNGs in drawable-hdpi/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true" >
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_action_delete_image" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_action_delete_image_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_action_delete_image_pressed" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_action_delete_image" />
    </selector>
```

color/link_text_red.xml: (link_text_focused_red_v2, link_text_pressed_red_v2, and link_text_red_v2 are defined in values/colors.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:color="@color/link_text_red_v2"
    android:state_window_focused="false" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/link_text_focused_red_v2"
        android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item
        android:color="@color/link_text_pressed_red_v2"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:color="@color/link_text_red_v2" />
</selector>
```

If you need something even more complex, you can use the attribute
`android:duplicateParentState="true"` in child layout elements of the Button, and its pressed state will be passed down the hierarchy.