# Android Button with Text with different images for Enabled and Pressed

Tags: android, image, button, drawable

I am trying to create a stateful Button having `Text` and an `Image` on the top via the following code:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnMultiplayer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/multiplayer"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:text="Multiplayer"/>
```

to get this:

[image: Image with button]

However, I couldn't find the way to change the drawable on the top when the image is pressed.

I tried to set `android:drawableTop` to `@drawable/multiplayer_stateful` where `@drawable/multiplayer_stateful` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawableTop="@drawable/multiplayer" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawableTop="@drawable/multiplayer_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

but this doesn't work. (Note that @drawable/multiplayer and @drawable/multiplayer_pressed are png files)

Any suggestions?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290966/how-do-you-change-the-drawable-image-on-a-button-with-text-to-reflect-pressed-st

Comment: Thank you. As i mentioned in the question, i am trying the same thing but it doesn't show the image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realized that i didn't use `android:dither="true"` in my selector statement. When I added it, it worked. If you can post this as an answer with an explanation to why `dither` is necessary, i can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `android:dither = "true"`

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:dither="true" >

<item android:drawableTop="@drawable/multiplayer" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawableTop="@drawable/multiplayer_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

From Android Docs:

> Enables or disables dithering of the bitmap if the bitmap does not
>   have the same pixel configuration as the screen (for instance: a ARGB
>   8888 bitmap with an RGB 565 screen).
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

Dithering affects how colors that are higher precision than the device are down-sampled. No dithering is generally faster, but higher precision colors are just truncated down (e.g. 8888 -> 565). Dithering tries to distribute the error inherent in this process, to reduce the visual artifacts.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

enable dither attribute in your selector.

**android:dither**

Boolean. Enables or disables dithering of the bitmap if the bitmap does not have the same pixel configuration as the screen (for instance: a ARGB 8888 bitmap with an RGB 565 screen).
For more detail refer this link:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html